# Batch Processing Framework for Managing Recomputations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, airflow, apache-beam, dataflow

My problem requires taking many source datasets, applying transformations to them to produce intermediate datasets and then several final datasets. Most of this data will be static, however, I need to support changing parameters in the transformations. This would mean that the result of that transformation as well as datasets that depend on it would need to be recalculated.

I've look briefly at Beam, Airflow, Flink and a few others, but they mainly seem focussed on either 1.) streaming or 2.) parallelization. Do any of these support invalidation of intermediate steps, or would some other library/framework be a better fit?

Thanks!

Comment: Using FLINK to batch process your dataset, should be fine. As long as adjusting the parameter, simply re-run the FLINK batch. FLINK supports batch/streaming both.

Comment: Are you looking to build a dyamic graph based on your options, or do you simply need to provide the set of static transforms for your graph a set of run time options?